# Command Button error

Tags: excel, vba, command, formulas

Can anyone help. Im having trouble with the following code. I keep getting error 1004.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A8").Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(DATA!L1:L20212<>""),DATA!L1:L20212)"
End Sub
```

What im after isthis code `=LOOKUP(2,1/(DATA!L1:L20212<>""),DATA!L1:L20212)` being entered into cell A8 by using a command button once the button has been sellected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes. Do this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A8").Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(DATA!L1:L20212<>""""),DATA!L1:L20212)"
End Sub
```

Notice how there are 4 double quotes in the formula (`<>""""`). Quotes inside a string that need to be written as part of the string need to be escaped with another double quote character, otherwise the code things it's the beginning/end of your string.

---

**ADDENDUM**

To answer your additional question in your comment, it's possible to remove this information when the form opens up. There's a form event you can handle (`UserForm_Activate`) to achieve this. For example, add the following to your form code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A8") = "" ' clear previous data
End Sub
```

This means that when the event fires, i.e. when the form is "activated", any previous data in range "A8" of the "Main Sheet" will be cleared.

---

**ADDENDUM 2**

To clear the value in range "A8" of the "Main Sheet" **when the workbook is opened** (my previous solution only clears it **when the userform is opened**), then you need to add an event handler to your workbook.

Open the `ThisWorkbook` Excel Object and add this in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A8") = "" ' clear previous data
End Sub
```

This event (`Workbook_Open`) fires when the workbook is opened. **It's very important to add this code in the `ThisWorkbook` object.**

Comment: Many Thanks, i wonder if their is a way to extend this further. when the form opens up it shows the reference number thats been created by the previous person. Is their a way to hide this until the command buttton has been submitted so it will then show and generate a new number

Comment: maybe my code needs cleaning up. Ive entered in your code but when the form opens up it still shows the previous reference number from the last person. it wont let me post the full code. Anyway of emailing you this code to take a look at. Thanks

Comment: maybe my code needs cleaning up. Ive entered in your code but when the form opens up it still shows the previous reference number from the last person.                                                   Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A8") = "" ' clear previous data
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Sheets("Main Sheet").Range("A8").Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/(DATA!L1:L20212<>""""),DATA!L1:L20212)"
End Sub

Comment: @GregRichards: Certainly works for me in Excel 2010. Are you sure you're looking at the right place, "Main Sheet", cell "A8"?

Comment: Yes A8, i see the reference but when i close the sheet and re-open it i still see the same info. Without having the code to write "=LOOKUP(2,1/(DATA!L1:L20212<>""""),DATA!L1:L20212)" yes it clears the cell but what i want is that cell A8 is clear when the book is opened so when the form is completed they hit the command button for it to produce a new ference number and saves the document. I hope you understand whay i mean. Sorry for the confussion. I appreciate all your help on this

Comment: @GregRichards: Ah, ok, I think I understand now. Please see my second addendum in my answer.